# Is there any way to use synchronous function call through Qt WebChannel?

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

Unlike `Qt WebKit Bridge`, I couldn't find to use synchronous function call on `JS side` using `Qt WebChannel`.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I've looked for such possibility as well and haven't found anything reasonable but using the scheme with event loop, possibly with timeout (like the scheme discussed [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/23550/making-asynchronous-calls-work-like-synchronous-calls/6). I ended up using JS calls asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's no way to do it. It is said in the documentation : [QWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html)

> Note that all communication between the HTML client and the QML/C++
>   server is asynchronous.

Moreover, it is precisely said in this blog : [Bridge the gap between C++/QML and the web](https://www.kdab.com/qt-webchannel-bridging-gap-cqml-web/)

> But, contrary to the WebKit Bridge, the API provided by the WebChannel
>   is completely asynchronous.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a synchronous `QWebChannel` call, but I found a way to achieve the desired functionality without using `QWebChannel` at all.

1. Create custom class `MyWebEnginePage` that inherits from `QWebEnginePage`.
2. Overload the `javaScriptPrompt(...)` method the following way:

   ```
   bool MyWebEnginePage::javaScriptPrompt(const QUrl &securityOrigin, const QString &msg, const QString &defaultValue, QString *result) {
       if (msg.length() > 1 && msg[0] == '^') {
           return processCommand(msg, defaultValue, result);
       }
       return QWebEnginePage::javaScriptPrompt(securityOrigin, msg, defaultValue, result);
   }
   ```
3. Add new method `bool processCommand(QString param1, QString param2, QString* result)`:

   ```
   bool MyWebEnginePage::processCommand(const QString& param1, const QString& param2, QString* result) {
       // parse param1 and/or param2 to determine what to do and get arguments
       char cmd = param1[1].toLatin1();
       if (cmd == '0') {
           // do something or call some method in c++
           QMessageBox::about(0, QString("Test"), QString("It works: ") + param2);
       }
       else if (cmd == '1') {
           // do something or call some method in c++ and return a string
           // the returned string can be encoded JSON object or base64 string
           *result = QString("some string to return: ") + param2;
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
4. Assign your `MyWebEnginePage` to `QWebEngineView`:

   ```
   view->setPage(new MyWebEnginePage());
   ```
5. In JavaScript create the following object:

   ```
   bridge = {
       doSomething: function (param) {
           window.prompt('^0', param);
       },
       doSomethingAndReturn: function (param) {
           // if you have more arguments encode them into a single string
           return window.prompt('^1', param);
       }
   };
   ```
6. Now You can communicate with C++ from JavaScript synchronously the following way:

   ```
   bridge.doSomething('input1');
   var returned_string = bridge.doSomethingAndReturn('input2');
   console.log(returned_string);
   ```
7. Original functionality of window.prompt still works but you can't use `^` symbol at the beginning of the message.

The disadvantage is that if you want to pass more arguments, you must first encode all them into the string (e.g. JSON format) and decode them in C++. The return value can be encoded and decoded in the same way in JavaScript bridge object.

You can also overload `javaScriptConfirm` method, but this can return only boolean value.